# How to fix x does not exist on type AppRouterInstance in Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I import `useRouter` from 'next/navigation? I get this error:

> Property 'query' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const {
    query: { id },
 back
} = useRouter();
```

If I use the old 'next/router', [I get this error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted) in browser. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because the 'query' object has been removed from useRouter hook. So right now, you have to use 'useSearchParams()'. Check out new documentation [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-search-params)